# a result of soul theorem,right?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

$X$ is an $n$-dim positively curved manifold and $Y$ is a totally geodesic submanifold of codimension 1. Then cutting along $Y$ we get $n$-dim positively curved manifolds without boundary, by soul theorem these manifolds should be homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. Am I right?If not,please give counterexamples.

Comment: yes, it is actually diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. 

Comment: Not sure what GB meant, but surely removing a geodesic from a paraboloid one can make it disconnected, so it is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. On a more serious note the soul theorem needs completeness (or total convexity), and even if $X$ were assumed complete, $X-Y$ won't be, so the soul theorem is irrelevant.


Comment: @Igor, I think he meant closed manifold and the distance function to the boundary, which is $Y$ is strictly concave, hence the interior of the component is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. Although this is not called Soul Theorem, but follows the same idea.

Comment: @GB: removing an equator from the round sphere makes it disconnected. Do you imply that components of $X-Y$ are always totally convex? If so, why?

Comment: I mean X-Y may be more than one connected component,but each of them is manifold homeo to R^n,right?

Comment: @GB: I look forward to seeing the proof of your claim.

Comment: @Igor, each component itself can be considered as a complete metric space, right?

Comment: @jiangsaiyin: I just added some relevant tags, I hope you don't mind. Are you Xumin?

Comment: Thank you!I don't know how to add tags,and tried so many times yesterday.I am not Xumin,my name is Jiang Yin,a student from China 

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your question correctly, the answer is yes. More precisely, the following statement should hold:

> If $X$ is a closed manifold of positive sectional curvature and $Y\subset X$ is a codimension one totally geodesic submanifold that disconnects $X$, then $X$ is homeomorphic to a sphere.

This follows, as the OP suggests, from the Soul Argument of Cheeger-Gromoll, extended to Alexandrov spaces by Perelman (see, e.g., [Section 6](http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/alexandrov/perelmanASWCBFB2+.pdf) of Perelman's notes). As mentioned in the comments, Cheeger-Gromoll's version of the argument actually suffices to get the conclusion.

A few details: denote by $C_1$ and $C_2$ the closure of the two connected components of $X\setminus Y$. These are positively curved compact Alexandrov spaces with boundary $Y$. On each of them, since the curvature is positive, the distance function to the boundary is concave. Therefore, the set of points at maximal distance (the soul) consists of a unique point. This implies that each $C_i$ is homeomorphic to a disk, hence $X=C_1\cup_{Y} C_2$ is a twisted sphere.

---

**edit** (to answer GB's comment): As discussed above, if $C$ a compact Alexandrov space with curvatures $\geq k>0$, then the soul $S=\{p\}$ is a point. Moreover, according to Perelman, the pairs $(C,\partial C)$ and $(\overline K(\Sigma_S),\Sigma_S)$ are homeomorphic (see [6.2](http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/alexandrov/perelmanASWCBFB2+.pdf) for proof), where $\Sigma_S$ is the space of directions at the soul and $\overline K(\Sigma_S)$ is the closure of the topological cone over $\Sigma_S$, i.e., the join of $\Sigma_S$ and a point. If $C$ is a manifold, the space of directions are spheres, so $(\overline K(\Sigma_S),\Sigma_S)$ is simply a pair $(D,\partial D)$, where $D$ is a disk.

Comment: @Renato, This argument is considered by Cheeger-Gromoll first. And here we don't need Alexandrov space theory to get the conclusion.

Comment: @GB: Yes, you're right, thank you. I edited the post to mention this.

Comment: @Renato, it seems you need more argument to conclude that Ci is homeomorphic to a closed disk. Since for Alexandrov space this is not true. It is not trivial, right?

Comment: @Renato,your answer is very good!But you assume X is closed,what is the result when X is not closed?And the Alexandrov space case?

Comment: @jiangsaiyin. When $X$ is not closed, $X$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb  R^n$ by Gromoll-Meyer. For ALexandrov space, Renato already pointed out it is homeomorphic to the closed cone over the space of directions at the soul point. (interior is homeomorphic to the open cone).

Comment: @Renato:If X is a closed manifold of positive sectional curvature and Y⊆X is a codimension one totally geodesic submanifold.Is it possible that Y doen not disconnect X?

Comment: @jiangsaiyin: Yes, take, e.g., the equatorial embedding of $Y=\mathbb RP^n$ inside $X=\mathbb RP^{n+1}$. Then $X\setminus Y$ only has one connected component. However, up to a double cover, the embedded hypersurface disconnects the manifold. The number of connected components of $X\setminus Y$ is the rank of $\tilde H_0(X\setminus Y)$ plus $1$. You can use the long exact sequence on the homology of the pair $(X,X\setminus Y)$ to prove that $X\setminus Y$ is connected if and only if the morphism $H_1(X)\to H_1(X,X\setminus Y)\cong\mathbb Z$ is nontrivial.

Comment: @Renato:My algebraic topology is poor.Why H_1(X,X-Y) iso to Z?And the exact sequence is ...-H_1(X-Y)-H_1(X)-H_1(X,X-Y)-H_0(X-Y)-0,I just know X-Y is connected if and only if H_0(X-Y)=Z,how can you get your last statement?